# Solid Waste Production, Globally? Spatially Resolved?

Tags: data-request, government, ngo

I would like to know the rate of production and content of municipal and industrial solid waste, globally in units of mass per area or mass per city or region.

I would be particularly interested in a globally standardized data set, but a few similar data sets from a few distinct regions would also be useful.

The [OECD Factbook](http://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/environment/oecd-factbook-2010/municipal-waste_factbook-2010-64-en) provides total waste by country, but I am looking for a more specific breakdown of the waste content, and a finer geographic resolution.

Comment: You might have better luck trying to find records on the rate of ingest at landfills & recycling centers.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found anything quite like what you want, but you might be able to build it from a bunch of separate datasets.

Many datasets have solid waste production/consumption on the level of buildings.

- https://data.weatherfordtx.gov/Government/Solid-Waste-Operating-Statistics/mvy8-6q2t?
- https://data.snostat.org/Government/Solid-Waste-Transfer-Station-Data-2012-/xn5u-y9xd?

Here's one with aggregates for the US.

- https://data.oregon.gov/Environment/Materials-Discarded-in-the-U-S-Municipal-Waste-Str/3g88-w2ag?

I found all of these by searching on [OpenPrism](http://openprism.thomaslevine.com/#/solid%20waste/1). You'll probably find more if you look through more of that search's results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but I think still active. For future searches, There's reasonably good data on municipal solid waste (MSW) for Colombia in www.sui.gov.co --> aseo --> reportes --> técnico-operativos --> "Disposición Final - Operador del Sitio de Disposición Final (Formatos 8 de la Circular SSPD-CRA de 2006 y 26 de la Resolución SSPD 15085 de 2009)"

In it, there's the following data:

- ID Empresa (company)
- Empresa
- Año/Mes (year/month)
- NUSD
- Nombre del Sitio de Disposición Final    (name of landfill)
- Origen   (origin)
- NUAP
- Nombre del área de Prestación (name of area serviced)
- Departamento (province)
- Municipio    (city/town)
- Toneladas Dispuestas (disposed tons)
- Fecha de Cargue (date of register)

As of today, the report could be accessed at: http://reportes.sui.gov.co/fabricaReportes/frameSet.jsp?idreporte=ase_com_125